# JavaScript: How to add multiple image slider on one page with same script?

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling with having more than one slider on one page. I have fixed some random problems like images not showing or disappearing with a search on stackoverflow but for this issue, I have been looking for an answer for similar issue but I didn't quite understand how they fixed it as only the fixed code were posted.

HOWEVER, as far as I understand, each slider div should have a different scripID but I cannot solve it.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card" class="col-md-3">
 <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
     <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
         <div class="mySlides fade">
             <img src="/images/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides fade">
             <img src="/images/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="/images/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

     <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
 <h2>Header </h2>
 <hr>
 <p class="hinfo">headerinfo</p>
 <p>Text info on the card</p>
 <p>Grey & Walnut colors<br>W:120 • D:120 • H:77</p>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

**CSS:**

````
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

</style>```
````

Comment: you need to add ID or unique class to each slider and pass it to the function showSlides, where you need to find the slides that belong to the id.

function showSlides(id, n) {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} .mySlides`);
    var dots = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} .dot`);
    ...
}

Comment: Sorry but it didn't make much sense to me. How do I give them ids and where should I add those in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add id to your container and add additional params to your functions so they can know which of the sliders need to be changed:

```
<div class="slideshow-container" id="first">

 <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
     <div class="mySlides fade">
         <img src="/images/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides fade">
         <img src="/images/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="/images/3.jpg">
     </div>

 <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
 <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex')">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex')">&#10095;</a>
  <br />
  <!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex')"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex')"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex')"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Your script:

```
<script>
    var indexes = {
        firstSliderIndex: 1,
        secondSliderIndex: 2,
    };
    showSlides(indexes.firstSliderIndex, 'first', 'firstSliderIndex');
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n, id, index) { // n - number of slide, id - container id, index - current slide number in slider
        showSlides(indexes[index] += n, id, index);
    }
    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n, id, index) {
        showSlides(indexes[index] = n, id, index);
    }

    function showSlides(n, id, index) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} .mySlides`);
        var dots = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} .dot`);
        if (n > slides.length) {
            indexes[index] = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {indexes[index] = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[indexes[index]-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[indexes[index]-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

Of course, this code can be refactored or modificated, but it's the easiest way